# A Regex pattern to split (possibly negative) integers separated with a hyphen

Tags: powershell

I need to split (possibly negative) integers separated with a hyphen and then turn those numbers into a range.  I can do the range part, the "split" boggles me.

```
"8-12"    # output =  8, 12
"-4--2"   # output = -4, -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your inputs, following could suffice

```
"8-12" -replace '(\d)-', '$1, '
"-4--2" -replace '(\d)-', '$1, '
```

The gist of this is to search for a decimal, capturing it in a group, followed by a hyphen. Replace each match with the captured group *(the decimal)*, a comma and a space.

[image: Result of run]

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind assertion to only split on `-` when preceded by a digit:

```
PS C:\> '-4--12' -split '(?<=\d)-'
-4
-12
```